# React Native save an image to iOS camera roll

Tags: react-native

How can I save an image in react native's  tag to iOS camera roll?  has a uri source. 
CameraRoll class has a method named saveImageWithTag but it's not clear how to use it. I think documentation is not good enough.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, and i check the react native CameraRoll API, it provide a static function

```
static saveImageWithTag(tag, successCallback, errorCallback)
```

Help you to save the image to the camera roll / gallery.

1.First, make sure your /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll/RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj has been correctly linked to your current project.If not, you should do it first by following the official document here. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#content)

2.Second, get your image source well-prepared.For me, I put it in the project assets-library.

3.Coding like this.In this case, I save my image when componentDidMount execute.
(Here is my reference link: https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/accessing-iphone-camera-roll-images-react-native)

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  CameraRoll,
  View,
} = React;

var CameraRollTest = React.createClass({
  
  componentDidMount() {
    CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag('YOUR_IMAGE_TAG/URI', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = CameraRollTest;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks you, I have added my implementation on my answer.